# CSS Relative link playing up

Tags: css, background-image, relative-path

I am trying to include a background image using a relative link in the css.

My tree looks like this

```
/_css
/_css/gcrm.css
/_images
/_images/bg-grad1.gif
```

The css I am using to use to call it is like so

```
background-image: url(../_images/bg-grad1.gif);
```

It displays as expected in Visual Web Developer however when I put it on the web, no background. When I inspect element in Chrome this is the linked file

```
mysite.com/_css/../_images/bg-grad.gif
```

Unfortunately I cannot link to it with the `/` root as I am trying to setup SSL and my hosting company has allowed us to use as shared cert that mirrors the site 1 level deep in the domain tree.

I must be missing something incredibly simple but I can't figure out what it is to get it working.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url looks fine in regards to your file structure. Assuming this is your file structure:

```
/_css/
    ...
    gcrm.css
    ...

/_images/
    ...
    bg-grad1.gif
    ...
```

From the fact that it's actually outputting the `..` in the url in the code, maybe you need to enclose the url in quotes:

`background-image: url("../_images/bg-grad1.gif");`

Comment: Yes, that is my file structure. I have tried both without quotes, with single quotes and with double quotes. A source at webmaster world reckoned it was due to having quotes...

Comment: Odd, your css seems fine to me.. what does the url for your css file show as in your header, including the link tags?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
background-image: url(../../_images/bg-grad1.gif);
```